# Summarize results per ID for different groups

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I am looking to summarize my results per `ID` (in this example just one shown) for each `domain`.

The idea is to get boolean values (`T/F`) for the three `actions` types (which are in a column), and place them in a row for each `ID`.

However, these results need to be grouped for each `domain` in the `URL` column.

Now, I can use `CASE WHEN` conditions to get the `T/F` values, however, then I don't get my results in a single row...

To get the domain I think I can use `SUBSTRING`.

Initial table:

```
+----+----------+----------------+
| ID | Action   | URL            |
+----+----------+----------------+
| 1  | Click    | www.google.com |
+----+----------+----------------+
| 1  | Hover    | www.google.com |
+----+----------+----------------+
| 1  | Download | www.reddit.com |
+----+----------+----------------+
```

Desired output:

```
+----+-------+-------+----------+------------+
| ID | Click | Hover | Download | Domain     |
+----+-------+-------+----------+------------+
| 1  | T     | T     | F        | google.com |
+----+-------+-------+----------+------------+
| 1  | F     | F     | T        | reddit.com |
+----+-------+-------+----------+------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use condition aggregation:

```
SELECT
    id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN action = 'Click' THEN 'T' ELSE 'F' END) click,
    MAX(CASE WHEN action = 'Hover' THEN 'T' ELSE 'F' END) hover,
    MAX(CASE WHEN action = 'Download' THEN 'T' ELSE 'F' END) download,
    SUBSTR(url, 5) domain
FROM mytable
GROUP BY id, SUBSTR(url, 5)
```

To generate the domain name, you can simply remove the first 4 characters from the url (hence this assumes that all urls begin with `'www.'`).

This **[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aXSw4B9qRDMsiZWtByBkgH/2)** with your sample data returns:

```
| id  | click | hover | download | domain     |
| --- | ----- | ----- | -------- | ---------- |
| 1   | T     | T     | F        | google.com |
| 1   | F     | F     | T        | reddit.com |
```